# swift -v returns <unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.12.sdk'

Tags: swift

I'm noob in swift, so what does the following mean and how to fix it?

In terminal:

```
> swift -v
> Apple Swift version 4.1.2 (swiftlang-902.0.54 clang-902.0.39.2)
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
> <unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.12.sdk'
```

my macOS is 10.13.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to Xcode preferences in the **Xcode** menu, or by tapping <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>:

  [image: preferences]
- In the **Locations** tab :

  [image: Locations]
- Set the Xcode version you want in **Command Line Tools** :

  [image: version]

*(I am using 9.4.1)*

Comment: thank a lot, @Carpsen90 ! I have the same version of Xcode and this fixes the issue!